# How to calculate the length of this curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, curves

Evaluate $L=\displaystyle \int\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$ where, $y=\dfrac{h}{2}\left[1-\cos{2\pi}\dfrac{x}{l}\right]$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to show the integral here, not hiding as an image you've posted.  Why are you interested in this arc length?  What have you tried with the integral?  Can you find the derivative, and just leave us with the integral to help you with?  Arc length is notorious for leading to impossible integrals; do you happen to know if this one should be doable or not?

Comment: Hello, I did not know about MathJax, but I suspected that there was a sytax I will use it in the future istead of pasting an image of an equation from Excel.  The function I provided represents the actual shape of a spring I am designing.  The length is needed to estimate material usage and a stress calculation.  Thank you!

Comment: Please make the effort to learn [how to format mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on this site and make the question self-contained. Links to images are strongly discouraged and even inline images are frowned upon, particularly if the content can be added directly to the question (as it can in this case). Your question should also include a description of what you have tried and what difficulty you encountered during those attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: HINT: The length of ellipse boundary is $ 2 \pi  \, a E(\epsilon) $ obtained by slant cutting of a cylinder radius $a$ This is same as the developed sine curve where $ 2 \pi a= l $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$y=\frac{\pi h}{l} \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi x}{l}\right),$$
and
$$L=\frac{l}{2 \pi} E\left(\frac{2 \pi x}{l} | - \frac{h^2 \pi^2}{l^2}\right),$$
where $E(x|m)$ is the incomplete [elliptic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) of the second kind.

Answer (score 0):

Picking the simplest possible case (i.e., $ h = 2, \ell = 2\pi$), so the integral becomes 
$$
\int \sqrt{1  + \sin^2(x)} ~ dx
$$
yields an elliptic integral of the second kind. Those are tabulated, of course, but the main message is "You're not going to get a nice answer for this."

On the other hand, you have Excel, right? Well...just compute a numerical approximation to the integral by subdividing into, say, 200 points. That'll give you enough accuracy that you'll know the length within a tiny multiple of $\ell$, and hence will have a pretty good cost estimate unless your spring is going to be miles long.

Answer (score 0):

As @S. Maths answered, you have
$$L=\frac{l }{2 \pi }E\left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{l}|-\frac{h^2 \pi ^2}{l^2}\right)$$ For a better legibility, let $k=-\frac{h^2 \pi ^2}{l^2}$ and $X=\frac{2 \pi  x}{l}$.

If $X$ is small, you could use, for an *approximation*, the series expansion
$$L=\frac{l }{2 \pi }\left(X-\frac{5 X^3}{3}-\frac{13 X^5}{6}-\frac{979 X^7}{126}-\frac{166627 X^9}{4536}+O\left(X^{11}\right)   \right)$$